# Qt5 C++11 расположение элементов, QGridLayout

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Располагаю элементы в своём приложении с `QGridLayout`.

Столкнулся с проблемой: не понимаю, почему происходит наложение виджетов.

Код:

```
add_file = new QPushButton("Открыть файл");
start = new QPushButton("->");
stop = new QPushButton("||");
test = new QTextEdit();

layout = new QGridLayout();
layout->addWidget(add_file, 1, 1, 1, 10, Qt::AlignTop);
layout->addWidget(test, 2, 1, 9, 10);
layout->addWidget(start, 10, 1, Qt::AlignBottom);
layout->addWidget(stop, 10, 2, Qt::AlignBottom);
```

Получается вот такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вроде ведь виджет `test` должен быть от (2,1) до (9,10), а виджеты `start` и `stop` в 10 строке, то есть ниже него. Или я что-то путаю?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте виджеты `add_file` и `test` разместить на два столбца:

```
layout = new QGridLayout()
layout->addWidget(add_file, 1, 1, 1, 2, Qt::AlignTop);
layout->addWidget(test, 2, 1, 1, 2);
layout->addWidget(start, 3, 1, Qt::AlignBottom);
layout->addWidget(stop, 3, 2, Qt::AlignBottom);
```

Comment: Получилось, теперь не накладывается
Но как сделать так, чтобы кнопки 'start' и 'stop' были маленькими, как у меня на скриншоте?

Comment: Тогда, вопрос пометьте как правильный. Ведь он касался расположения элементов. А насчет кнопок, задайте им размер, для этого есть методы: setFixedWidth, setFixedHeight, setFixedSize. Или задайте политику размеров через setSizePolicy

Comment: про кнопки: можно сделать ширину всего, как было, 10... Но вообще ИМХО лучше отказаться от QGridLayout в пользу комбинации Q[VH]BoxLayout. У первого очень ограниченная сфера применения, где он смотрится лцчше остальных...

Answer (score 3):

> Вроде ведь виджет test должен быть от (2,1) до (9,10), а виджеты start и stop в 10 строке, то есть ниже него. Или я что-то путаю?

Да, путаешь,

```
layout->addWidget(test, 2, 1, 9, 10);
```

означает начало в (2,1) и высотой/шириной (9,10), соответственно он продолжается до ячейки 11.